# C# Out of range with substring

Tags: c#, substring

I try to fill a string[] like this:

```
public string Reception = "";
public void SaveData()
{
 int lengthReception = Reception.Length; //i got 19
 string[] Data = new Data[lengthReception];
 for(int i = lengthReception, i>0, i--)
 {
  Data[i] = Reception.Substring(i,1); //i try to store one charactere by case
 }                                    //but i got error message ArgumentOutOfRangeException
}
```

So i want to store one charactere by case. My Substring look good according to doc microsoft?!

Thanks you for help !

Comment: Your for loop should be `for(int i = lengthReception - 1 , i>=0, i--)`

Comment: `int i = lengthReception - 1`, upper bound or array is exclusive, `i>=0` lower is inclusive

Comment: Arrays are zero-based in C#. So `int i = lengthReception - 1` and `i  >= 0`.

Comment: [Why are zero-based arrays the norm?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/110804/6335)

Comment: A `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>` so you can iterate through a string, character by character with a `foreach`. Then you can convert each character to a string with `char.ToString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Reception.Length` is `19`, there is no char at index `19` or higher.

This works:

```
public void SaveData()
{
    int lengthReception = Reception.Length; //= 19
    string[] Data = new string[lengthReception];
    for (int i = lengthReception - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Data[i] = Reception.Substring(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Substring(Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1)

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
> specified character position and has a specified length.

In the first iteration, your code will explode.

```cs
 Data[i] = Reception.Substring(i,1); //i will be 19 at first. Array is 0 index based...so last available index is 18; not 19.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string` class implements `IEnumerable<char>` allowing a string to be iterated over using `foreach`.  Using that feature (and fixing a line of your code) yields:

```
private static string Reception = "This is a test";
private static void SaveData()
{
    int lengthReception = Reception.Length;
    //I am assuming that you intended to create a new string array on the next line
    string[] Data = new string[lengthReception];
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var c in Reception)
    {
        Data[index++] = c.ToString();
    }
}
```

Being *off by one* is something you should expect when you are developing code.  You should learn to debug your way through these issues.  And, it helps if you avoid *off by one* sinkholes (like `string.Substring`) in your code.  That's what this answer does.